# Condition on the Young's function

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, banach-spaces, orlicz-spaces

I am reading the paper "[Fractional integration in Orlicz spaces](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267048828_Fractional_Integration_in_Orlicz_Spaces)" by R. Sharpley.

And I would like to understand one question:

Let $A,B, C$ are Young's functions. The spaces $L_A, L_B$ are Orlicz spaces and spaces $M(A), M(B)$ are Lorentz spaces corresponding to $L_A, L_B$ respectively.

Set $\phi_K(t)=1/K^{-1}(1/t)$, for $K=A,B,C$ are concave non-decreasing functions.

And I would like to understand whether the Young's condition
$$
s\phi_C(s)\leq c\phi_A(s)\phi_B(s)
$$
is sufficient to guarantee that
$$
M(A)\ast M(B) \subset \Lambda(C),
$$
where $\Lambda(C)$ is a Banach space of all locally integrable functions such that $\int_0^{\infty} f^*(s)d\phi_A(s)$ is finite.